# Database Design for a Person's Availability

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I am currently working on a web application that stores information of Cooks in the user table. We have a functionality to search the cooks from our web application. If a cook is not available on May 3, 2016, we want to show the `Not-Bookable` or `Not-Available` message for that cook if user performs the search for May 3, 2016. The solution we have come up to is to create a table named CooksAvailability with following fields

```
ID, //Primary key, auto increment
IDCook, //foreign key to user's table
Date, //date he is available on
AvailableForBreakFast, //bool field
AvailableForLunch, //bool field
AvailableForDinner, //book field
BreakFastCookingPrice, //decimal nullable
LunchCookingPrice, //decimal nullable
DinnerCookingPrice //decimal nullable
```

With this schema, we are able to tell if the user is available for a specific date or not. But the problem with this approach is that it requires a lot of db space i.e if a cook is available for 280 days/year, there has to be 280 rows to reflect just one cook's availability.

This is too much space given the fact that we may have potentially thousands of cooks registered with our application. As you can see the CookingPrice fields for breakfast, lunch and dinner. it means a cook can charge different cooking rates for cooking on different dates and times.

Currently, we are looking for a smart solution that fulfils our requirements and consumes less space than our solution does.

Comment: How much space is too much space?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question I should know more about the structure of the information.
For example if most cooks are available in a certain period, it could be helpful to organize your availability table with

avail_from_date - avail_to_date, instead of a row for each day.

this would reduce the amount of rows.

The different prices for breakfast, lunch and dinner could be stored better in the cooks table, if the prices are not different each day. Same is for the a availability for breakfast, lunch and dinner if this is not different each day.

But if your information structure makes it necessary to keep a record for every cook every day this would be 365 * 280 = 102,200 records for a year, this is not very much for a sql db in my eyes. If you put the indexes at the right place this will have a good performance.

Comment: The thing is that cook can have different rates/day/meal. It means he might have one rate for 16 may 2016 breakfast and another rate for 17 may 2016 breakfast

Comment: and if we have 10000 cooks for example, we will end up with 10000 * 280 = 2800000 rows (almost three million rows). and I believe that are too much or isn't it. Please guide me, I am not the db guy

Comment: No not in general too much, if you need it.
I mean there is no other way if there is a different price an or availability each day.
But you have to analyze and normalize your data: For e.g. in there are not daily differences, but mothly - you have to put them in an montly table...

Comment: So the question is not what is too much size, the question is what do you need exactly to store the real information optimal.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing a record for each day and the main mistake, which led you to this redundant design was that you did not separate the concepts enough.

I do not know whether a cook has an expected rate for a given meal, that is, a price one can assume in general if one has no additional information. If that is the case, then you can store these default prices in the table where you store the cooks.

Let's store the availability and the specific prices in different tables. If the availability does not have to store the prices, then you can store availability intervals. In the other table, where you store the prices, you need to store only the prices which deviate from the expected price. So, you will have defined availability intervals in a table, specific prices when the price differs from the expected one in the oter and default meal price values in the cook table, so, if there is no special price, the default price will be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions that would help with the overall answer.

1. How often does availability change?
2. How often does price change?
3. Are there general patterns, e.g. cook X is available for breakfast and lunch, Monday - Wednesday each week?
4. Is there a normal availability / price over a certain period of time,
   but with short-term overrides / differences?

If availability and price change at different speeds, I would suggest you model them separately.  That way you only need to show what has changed, rather than duplicating data that is constant.

Beyond that, there's a space / complexity trade-off to make.

At one extreme, you could have a hierarchy of configurations that override each other.  So, for cook X there's set A that says they can do breakfast Monday - Wednesday between dates 1 and 2.  Then also for cook X there's set B that says they can do lunch on Thursday between dates 3 and 4.  Assuming that dates go 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2, you can define whether set B overrides set A or adds to it.  This is the most concise, but has quite a lot of business logic to work through to interpret it.

At the other extreme, you just say for cook X between date 1 and 2 this thing is true (an availability for a service, a price).  You find all things that are true for a given date, possibly bringing in several separate records e.g. a lunch availability for Monday, a lunch price for Monday etc.